# Parse between slashes within URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse two numbers within a URL. The URL is here:

http://movies.actionpaxed.com/5600_5949/5943/5/pics/none/500k/3min/003.jpg?nvb=20130811232301&nva=20130812012301&hash=090a687f7e27b2f5ef735

I'm trying to only get the "5943/5" portion of the URL. I would just parse the URL, then use str_replace, but the folders around the two I need, vary in name.

So far I have:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
$link = parse_to_string('"video_url":"', '"};', $homepage);
$link = str_replace(array( '"low":"', '"};'), '', $link);
$link = utf8_decode(urldecode($link));
```

At the end of this code, $link = http://movies.actionpaxed.com/5600_5949/5943/5/pics/none/500k/3min/003.jpg?nvb=20130811232301&nva=20130812012301&hash=090a687f7e27b2f5ef735

Any help with the regex expression that can take care of this for me, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
$res = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
$res = $res[2].'/'.$res[3];
echo $res;
```

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/myyrOuxt)**

Comment: Those first two lines could be combined if you used the second argument for [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), e.g. `$res = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH))`.  And I think you'll want indexes 1 and 2, not 2 and 3?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the leading slash would be in the path . . . hence indexes 2 and 3 . . . nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$exploded = explode("/", $link);
$res = $exploded[4] . "/" . $exploded[5];

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('%https?://.*?/\d*_\d*/(\d*)/(\d*)%',$link,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that extracts what you are looking for.

```
function getTheStuff($url) {

    // Only get the part of the URL that
    // actually matters; this makes the
    // problem smaller and easier to solve
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

    // The path will be false if the URL is
    // malformed, or null if it was not found
    if ($path !== false && $path !== null) {

        // Assuming that the stuff you need is
        // always after the first forward slash,
        // and that the format never changes,
        // it should be easy to match
        preg_match('/^\/[\d_]+\/(\d+\/\d+)/', $path, $result);

        // We only capture one thing so what we
        // are looking for can only be the second
        // thing in the array
        if (isset($result[1])) {
            return $result[1];
        }
    }
    // If it is not in the array then it
    // means that it was not found
    return false;
}
$url = 'http://movies.actionpaxed.com/5600_5949/5943/5/pics/none/500k/3min/003.jpg?nvb=20130811232301&nva=20130812012301&hash=090a687f7e27b2f5ef735';
var_dump(getTheStuff($url));
```

If I were writing this for myself then I would have avoided the regular expression. It is the easiest in this case, so I used it. I would probably have generalized the solution by tokenizing the `$path` (using `/` as a delimiter), and then let another function/method/mechanism handle extracting the parts that are needed. That way it would be easier to adopt it for other URLs that are formatted differently.